# Drupal Commons 3 and Original Drupal Core Updates

Tags: updating, security

I'm may be planning to switch over to Drupal Commons 3. When the original Drupal core gets security updates, will I be able to get those updates in the Drupal Commons or do I have to wait for Drupal Commons to release their own patch? I'm not sure if Drupal Commons modifies the original Drupal Core's code. Sorry if this question is already answered in an FAQ somewhere but I couldn't find the answer and I'm pretty new to Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Commons team has committed to having a new release of commons within a short period after a core or contrib security release so you should just be able to upgrade by following the Commons upgrade procedure.

It's a bit risky to update core or contrib modules inside of a distribution. If you can do it on a test site first, confirm that it's working, and report your problems with the test site to the issue queue then you'll help getting the fully packaged Commons out.

Comment: Yeah the only thing that worries me is that if i proceed to use Drupal Commons, I will be depending on the commons team to release a patch shortly after a core security release. I don't want to be "screwed" when commons is not being maintained in the future...which is why i'm wondering if it is alright for me to update the core the way i would if i use the original Drupal 7.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say it's okay to update anything from the distro manually, unless you really know what you're doing and can handle the pain (of incompatibility, of a lost patch, of using non-supported code that makes your support requests almost invalid).

Disclaimer: I co-maintain Commerce Kickstart.

Comment: "Really know what you're doing" boils down to "do it in a test environment first and then test out your features." The problems are usually smaller with a core security update b/c core usually has a release that *just* includes the security change. Regarding depending on the Commons team - they've committed to doing the release rapidly and their focus is on the 7.x-3.x version so I encourage you to trust them...AND do your tests and give feedback in the issue queue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same dilemma. Advice I've received includes checking my requirements to see if I need everything that Commons 3 has, or rather, whether there is something in C3 that I couldn't build quickly with available modules. If the answer to both questions i No, then forget C3. Nevertheless, as a non-programmer/non-developer, I think Commons is great as an out of the box solution, but notwithstanding the option to test/experiment with modules/upgrades on your own, you are committing yourself to the Commons Team and their development cycle (and note the timescale for the Drupal 7 version).

Personally, I like Commons 3, and know that Acquia will continue its development, however.