# Drupal 7 Commons 3 Vs Drupal Core + Commons modules

Tags: 7

I read [Drupal Commons 3 and Original Drupal Core Updates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65115/drupal-commons-3-and-original-drupal-core-updates) and I wonder what the difference between installing the Drupal Commons 7 distributions and installing Drupal 7 plus the Drupal Commons modules available freely on Drupal.org is.

It seems to be safer to use Drupal core and the modules, and not to rely on entire distro updates.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. You have not asked a question here. Even if it were worded as a question, it would still be a duplicate of the post you referenced. Please review the FAQ.

Comment: Individual updates are always harder and more buggy than entire distro updates, because you don't have the distro maintainer doing regression testing and testing all modules together, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Commons 2.x really had a lot of customizations in the install profile, deploying a well organized social network, but when i installed Commons 3.x, i had a sense of "hey, does it really customized anything?", that seems to be your feeling too.

I don't know the roadmap of the project, but it seems a little "naked" in this first version, compared to what they had inside the last Commons 2.x version.

For a project starting now, with what Commons 3.0 has to offer in the install profile(they can improve it, but if you install now, the newer versions of it will not came to you by just upgrading the modules), i think that what you're proposing could be a good thing, because my experience with Commons 2.x updates were really painful just to get some more views and panels improvements(and had to deal with so many Feature overrides), so it could be easier if YOU mantain your own profile, maybe creating one or using the Minimal or Standard themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had to work on a project, based on Commons v3 (the distribution itself).

My personal observations:

-Some functions have different functionality.

-Generally, less documentation.

-Organic groups module: different functionality.

-Bug with Rules module ;) (Contributed Rules are not visible if you edit them).

For some functionalities we had to tweak Commons core functions (to revert to normal Drupal behaviour).

At the project evaluation we (the team) concluded we shouldn't have used Commons, but normal Drupal core + Commons modules.

That was my humble opinion.

Comment: I tried to install commons hashtags and commons topic module in one of my site, but it gave me fatal error. I wanted to have a hashtags functionality on my site, I previously installed [hashtags module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hashtags), but it was not converting to links so I tried to install commons modules. Any solution?

Comment: what was the fatal error ?

Comment: Something like this `"Fatal error: Call to undefined function commons_entity_integration_info() in /blablabla/modules/contrib/commons_topics/commons_topics.module on line 54".` FYI I am not using commons.

Comment: @Umair I know this was years ago but I just ran into the same issue. It's because that function is defined in the commons.profile file in the profiles folder. Which isn't going to be used if that install profile wasn't used. This is not a permanent solution but I was able to get it working by defining that function in commons_topics.module by copy pasting it from commons.profile